# If X and Y both have finite nth moment then so does X + Y

Tags: probability, probability-theory, proof-verification

I wanted to make sure that my proof was sound enough. I have that given we know $E[X]^n\ ,\ E[Y]^n<\infty$ we simply use the linearity of expectation which follows:

$E[X+Y]=E[X]+E[Y]$

$E[X+Y]^n=E[X]^n+E[Y]^n$

Since each term is finite, their sum is finite  $E[X]^n+E[Y]^n < \infty$, so

$E[X+Y]^n< \infty$

Comment: $ \mathbb E[(X+Y)^n ] \neq \mathbb E[X^n] + \mathbb E[Y^n]$.  Hint: (Assuming $n \in \mathbb N$). Prove that for $m \in \{0,...,n\}$ both $\mathbb E[X^m], \mathbb E[Y^m]$ are finite. Use $(a+b)^n = \sum_{m=0}^n {n \choose m} a^m b^{n-m}$ and apply linearity of expectation.

Comment: @DominikKutek If $X$ and $Y$ are integrable it doesn't follow that $XY$ is integrable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: For integer $n\ge1$ use the fact that the function $f(x):=|x|^n$ is convex to derive the inequality
$$
f\left(\frac{x+y}2\right)\le \frac{f(x)+f(y)}2
$$
which you then apply to $X$, $Y$ to obtain
$$
|X+Y|\le 2^{n-1}(|X|^n+|Y|^n)
$$

---

Another approach is to observe the inequalities, valid for all non-negative $a,b$:
$$\max\{a,b\}\stackrel{(1)}\le a+b\stackrel{(2)}\le 2 \max\{a,b\}.$$ Since the triangle inequality gives $|X+Y|\le |X|+|Y|$, we apply (1) and (2) to get
$$
|X+Y|^n\le (|X|+|Y|)^n\stackrel{(2)}\le(2\max\{|X|,|Y|\})^n=2^n\max\{|X|^n,|Y|^n\}\stackrel{(1)}\le 2^n(|X|^n+|Y|^n).
$$

Answer (score 0):

No, your proof is not correct. Rather it is $\mathbb E[X^n]$ not $\mathbb E[X]^n$ that is relevant when computing the $n^{th}$ moment - the former is the $n^{th}$ moment, the latter is equal to the first moment raised to the $n^{th}$ power.

As mentioned in the comments, you can find a correct proof using the binomial theorem.

For completeness, there is another way I will present here, using [characteristic functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_(probability_theory)), under the further assumption that $X$ and $Y$ are independent. Let $\phi_X(t),\phi_Y(t)$ be the characteristic functions of $X$ and $Y$ respectively. Then
$$
\phi_{X+Y}(t)=\phi_X(t)\phi_Y(t).
$$
Existence of $n^{th}$ moment is equivalent to existence of $n^{th}$ derivative at $t=0$ of the characteristic function, since
$$
\mathbb E[X^n]=(-i)^n\phi_X^{(n)}(0).
$$
Since the product of two functions with $n^{th}$ derivative existing at a point also has the property, we are done.